# Как оптимизировать размер видео файла в телеграм-боте на aiogram 3.4

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x

Научился отправлять видео в боте при нажатии на кнопку.
На декстопе все приходит как надо в нужном размере картинки, но на телефоне видео форматируется и становится шире.
Как сделать чтобы видео было без форматирования?
Вот обработчик нажатия:

```
@dp.message(F.text == 'Пункт1')
async def upload_video(message: Message):
   file_ids: list 

   video_from_pc = FSInputFile("Buton_candle\План обучения\Обзор_воска.MOV")
   result = await message.answer_video(
      video_from_pc,
      caption='Пункт1 - обзор воска')
   file_ids.append(result.video[-1].file_id)
```